# Dynamic price and filter by price widget woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I use the «[Exchange Rates Today](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/exchange-rates-today/)» plugin to display prices based on the exchange rate (the developer apparently no longer supports it). But the plugin still works for me as it should: the cost of the product is specified in$, in the settings of this plugin, the currency exchange rate is specified and the price is displayed on the site, taking into account the rate.

Problem with the Filter by Price widget from woocommerce. It takes into account the price specified in the admin panel, but does not filter the price on the site. Is it possible to somehow catch on here, so that the widget does not filter the cost specified in the site admin panel, but this dynamic price?

The plugin code is below:

```php
add_action ('admin_menu', 'dynamic_price_button');
//Simple product
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_price_filter_widget_min_amount', 'custom_price', 99, 2);
add_filter( 'woocommerce_price_filter_widget_max_amount', 'custom_price', 99, 2);
// Variable
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_regular_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 );
// Variations
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_price', 'custom_price', 99, 3 );
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_regular_price', 'custom_price', 99, 3 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_prices_sale_price',    'custom_price', 99, 3  );
// Handling price caching (see explanations at the end)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_variation_prices_hash', 'add_price_multiplier_to_variation_prices_hash', 99, 1 );

add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_mysettings' );

function register_mysettings () {
    register_setting( 'baw-settings-group', 'kurs' );
    register_setting( 'baw-settings-group', 'valuta' );
}

function custom_price ($price) {
    $int = floatval($price);
    $kurs=get_option('kurs');
    if ($kurs!='') {
        return $int*$kurs;
    } else  return  $int;
}

function add_price_multiplier_to_variation_prices_hash($hash){
    $hash[] = get_option('kurs');
    return $hash;
}

function dynamic_price_button () {
    add_submenu_page ('woocommerce', 'Курс сегодня', 'Курс сегодня', 'manage_options', 'dynamic_price', 'setting_page');
}

function setting_page () {
?>
<div class="wrap">
<h2>Курс на сегодня</h2>
<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php settings_fields( 'baw-settings-group' ); ?>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">Курс</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="kurs" value="<?php echo get_option('kurs'); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>               
    </table>

    <p class="submit">
    <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save Changes') ?>" />
    </p>

</form>
</div>
<?php }

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'filter_function_name_3276', 10, 2 );
function filter_function_name_3276( $meta_query ){
    if ( isset( $_GET['max_price'] ) || isset( $_GET['min_price'] ) ) { // WPCS: input var ok, CSRF ok.
            $kurs=get_option('kurs');
            if (isset($_GET['min_price']) && $_GET['min_price']>0){
                $meta_query['price_filter']['value'][0] =  $meta_query['price_filter']['value'][0]/$kurs;
            };
            if (isset($_GET['max_price'])){
                $meta_query['price_filter']['value'][1] =  $meta_query['price_filter']['value'][1]/$kurs;
            };
            return $meta_query;
    }
    return $meta_query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

woocommerce\includes\class-wc-query.php Lines 529-530 :

```
$current_min_price = isset( $_GET['min_price'] ) ? floatval( wp_unslash( $_GET['min_price'] ) ) : 0; // WPCS: input var ok, CSRF ok.
$current_max_price = isset( $_GET['max_price'] ) ? floatval( wp_unslash( $_GET['max_price'] ) ) : PHP_INT_MAX;
```

Change for:

```
$kurs=get_option('kurs');

$current_min_price = isset( $_GET['min_price'] ) ? floatval( wp_unslash( $_GET['min_price'] ) / $kurs ) : 0; 
$current_max_price = isset( $_GET['max_price'] ) ? floatval( wp_unslash( $_GET['max_price'] ) / $kurs ) : PHP_INT_MAX;
```